# Merging a List<HashMap<Obj1, Obj2>> as List<HashMap<Ob1, List<Obj2>>> in an efficient way?

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a data structure as

```
List<HashMap<Person, Address>>
```

I have a list from which I am getting the Person and Address objects. After I am done iterating over the given list, I need to merge the Address for each Person and get something as

```
List<HashMap<Person1, Address1>>
List<HashMap<Person1, Address2>>
List<HashMap<Person2, Address3>>
```

to

```
List<HashMap<Person, List<Address>>>
```

Is there any efficient way to get this done - may be having a different approach? Or iterating  the list is only option. And if the list contains a lot of data what would be the best option to treat it?

Comment: The iteration thing, setting a flag and all. But that is not helping. I think its only complicating the problem.

Comment: Just do it the most obvious way. If you have a specific issue then, write another question.

Comment: What is the benefit of using List over Map? Why you need to do that?

Comment: What's the point of generating a list of maps? I'm not sure what transformation you are trying to achieve. It would seem that a single map would be enough to capture all the data.

Comment: @TedHopp -I think using list is an overkill. How do I go about merging the Map based on my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your list of maps to a single map from `Person` to a list (set?) of addresses as follows:

```
Map<Person, List<Address>> restructure(List<Map<Person, Address>> data) {
    Map<Person, List<Address>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map<Person, Address> map : data) {
        for (Map.Entry<Person, Address> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            List<Address> addresses = result.get(entry.getKey());
            if (addresses == null) {
                addresses = new LinkedList<>(); // or ArrayList, or ...
                result.put(p, addresses);
            }
            addresses.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Collections Multimap

```
    List<HashMap<Person, Address>> list = ...
    HashMultimap<Person, Address> mm = HashMultimap.create();
    for (HashMap<Person, Address> m : list) {
        for(Entry<Person, Address> e : m.entrySet()) {
            mm.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }
```

note that it can hold Persons and their Addresses without List

Comment: Note that `HashMultimap` doesn't hold duplicate key-value pairs - it's more analogous to a `Map<Person, Set<Address>>`.

Comment: Also Spring has [`LinkedMultiValueMap`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html) which extends `Map<K,List<V>>`.